# How to make our bot read other bot embed message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so I am trying to make a companion bot for a bot called "EPIC RPG" it is a game bot and there are some events that I would like my bot to ping a role so people notice there is an event going on but I just can't make my bot read the embed, any ideas?[this is the EPIC RPG EVENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh3h3.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Message.embeds`. It returns an array of all the embeds in the message. Since a bot can send only 1 embed per messages, message.embeds[0] will return a `MessageEmbed` object of the embed.

So you can use the following code:

```js
let embed = message.embeds[0];
embed.title // the title of the embed
embed.description // the description of the embed
```

[EDIT] full code:

```js
client.on('message', message => { 
let embed = message.embeds[0];
if (message.author.id == 'epicrpgbot_id' && embed && embed.fields && embed.fields[0].title == 'IT'S RAINING COINS') {
// replace 'epicrpgbot_id with the bot's id
message.channel.send(`Embed
title: ${embed.title}
description: ${embed.description}
// replace this with the message you want to write 
${client.users.cache.get('bot_id')} // replace 'bot_id' with the epic rpg bot's id.
`);
}
});
```

Comment: sorry i dont understand, then how we auto reply it with with my bots

Comment: let embed = message.embeds[0];
if (!embed) return;
console.log(embed.title);
console.log(embed.description);

Comment: Put this at the top of `client.on('message', message => ...)` and send that embed. There will be embed title and description at the console.

Comment: still dont understand cuz all I want is I want my bot to read the other bot embed messages, then my bot reply it with role mention and a message.

Comment: So that is how to read other bot's embed messages and here is the replyig code:

message.reply(`${message.guild.roles.cache.get('role_id')} message`);

Comment: can u write the full command of this? im getting confused thanks

Comment: thanks dude, it really helping me a lot, but i have 1 problem again lol, your code seems reacting to any embed messages from any bot, but i want my bot only react to "EPIC RPG" bot in spesific word

Comment: thanks, but how do i detect only in the embed message field that write "IT'S RAINING COINS" thanks

Comment: You mean the embed title?

Comment: Then, the field title or description?

Comment: i think the "IT'S RAINING COINS"is on field title

Comment: Edited the answer!

Comment: OMFG IT'S WORK SIR, THANK YOU SO MUCH